# i have a bug when filter a custom field joined with other table in collection grid admin magento 2

Tags: magento2

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider{
function getData(){
/**  @var  \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$collection->addNameToSelect()
->addFieldToFilter('group_id', ['in' => [1,7]])
->addFieldToFilter('player_number', ['nin' => [null, '']])
->addFieldToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect(['player_number', 'player_nickname'], 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect(['team_id'], 'inner')
->getSelect()->joinLeft(
'sales_order_grid',
'sales_order_grid.customer_id=e.entity_id',
'customer_name'
);
}
}

- message error : {"error":"The "customer_name" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.","errorcode":"0"}
- 'e' is customer_entity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such attribute called customer_name in Magento 2.
but you can fetch first_name, last_name instead.

Comment: 'customer_name'  i find in table "sales_order_grid"

Comment: Use sales_order_grid.customer_name there.

Comment: thank you, I remove generated/* and It is working.